# Mvc Grid Initial Column Filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using this grid : [Grid.MVC](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Setup%20initial%20column%20filtering&referringTitle=Documentation) and try to apply custom filtering at start of the page. My question is how to add grid-init parameter to query string i complitly don't know how to do it. I'm quite new to asp.net MVC.  Any help is appreciated

**Update :** 
I was able to sort this by adding :

```
  protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string originalPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.ToLower();
        if (originalPath == "/") Context.RewritePath("/?grid-init=1");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all: you are in MVC not ASP classic. It means you need model and controller for your view not initializing method!.

Second: if you configure GridMVC properly, including adding bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap-datepicker.js, the only thing you need to have filtering in you view, is adding ".Filterable()" in GridMVC column or GridMVC itself for filtering that colum or all GridMVC columns.

Comment: yes i know but looka at this site https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Setup%20initial%20column%20filtering&referringTitle=Documentation you need to set up grid-init parameter in query string